# Compare InDesign Document with Word OR PDF file

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript, indesign-server

I am working with the InDesign Scripts to compare Word or PDF with InDesign Document. Can anyone help me with the following:

**1. Compare a client provided PDF with my InDesign Document to compare Line-Breaks, Page-Breaks & Page Composition. Then apply the differences found in the my Indesign Document.**

**OR**

**2. Compare a word document with the InDesign Document to compare Line-Breaks, Page-Breaks & Page Composition. Then apply the differences found in the my Indesign Document.**

Is there any InDesign Feature/Script to perform the this task or anyone can refer me any DotNet library/code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Vector document comparison is in general a hard topic, and what you refer to - semantic layout comparison (e.g. detecting line breaks) - is rather extreme. Having worked with vector documents for over 10 years, I can't point any generic tool or library you could use for that.

Commercial publishing software usually applies simpler approach based on rendering pages first and then **comparing output images pixel-by-pixel**. Going this way, you could start with exporting compared documents as PDFs or raster images and then comparing with [something like *ImageMagick*](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29277).

Alternatively, you could look for a way to convert compared documents to vector, layout-preserving format first (like HTML), and find something to [compare in that format](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compare+html).

Good luck !
Let me know if you found something :-)